# NuGet : How can i apply transform to .csdef file of Cloud project

Tags: azure, nuget, nuget-package

I am creating NuGet Package and facing one issue that how can i apply transformation to file that is not web.config or app.config , i would like to make transformation to ServiceDefination.csdef file that's why i have put file named as **ServiceDefination.csdef.transform** in /content folder.

When i am trying to install that nuget simply make copy of that file in root named as **ServiceDefination.csdef.transform.txt**

Can i apply transformation to .csdef file or is it limited to web.config & app.config?

thanks

Comment: There is a [blog post](http://www.olegsych.com/2010/12/config-file-transformation/) of how to do **Web.config** style transforms on cscfg files. I'm not sure if this will cover the full scope of your problem, but it outlines part of what you're attempting to do.

Comment: sorry but this all about environment specific transformation i have concerned with nuget pacakge related transformation as it can be possible with only web.config and app.config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nuget config transformations actually work on **ANY XML file** using the same *.transform convention (except for packages.config, for which there are other hacks/workarounds).

If you simply need to transform (read: add/merge changes into) the csdef file, this should work.

If not, you can attempt the PowerShell route and modify the target file using an XML template file embedded in your package. If you need inspiration on how to do so, you can find an example package which generates a certain XML file (actually a nuspec file) here:
https://github.com/myget/NuGetPackages/blob/master/NuSpec/tools/init.ps1

Also, if the question still stands, could you please mention which version of nuget you are using?